# Changing HTML paragraph based on variable calculation

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to multiply two variables and output the result into a paragraph.

This is my script

```
function product() {
var first = $('input[name=amount]').val();
var second = $('#ipayoutdyn').val();
var productof = first*second;
$("#iwindyn").html(productof);
}
```

HTML

```
<input id='inpamount' type="text" name="amount" value="2.00" onkeyup="pad();validatemin();product()">

<p id = "iwindyn">3.84</p>
```

I have tried this but it does not seem to work. Can anyone suggest a problem? Thanks

Using parseFloat() and assigning text values to the HTML elements fixed the issue.

```
function product() {
var first = $('input[name=amount]').val();
var second = parseFloat($('#sidetextdyn').text());
var productof = first*second;
$("#iwindyn").html(productof);
}
```

Comment: What output are you getting @Semger?

Comment: Are you using chrome? If so in the developer tools are you seeing any errors? Have you included jQuery in your HTML file? More code context would be helpful.

Comment: @Varun @RandomWebGuy I do not see any errors, and I have included jquery. Is my syntax correct? Am i appending the `#iwindyn` correctly? I also edited my answer to include the HTML i am trying to append.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your selector for your `input` with name `amount` needs quotes:

```
var first = $('input[name="amount"]').val();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="amount"/>
<input id="ipayoutdyn"/>
<input id='inpamount' type="text" name="amount" value="2.00" onkeyup="product()"/>
<div id="iwindyn"></div>

<script>
    function product() {
        var first = $('input[name="amount"]').val();
        var second = $('#ipayoutdyn').val();
        var productof = first*second;
        $("#iwindyn").html(productof);
    }    
</script>
```

now when you type in the 3rd textbox, it triggers `product()` function and the result is shown `#iwindyn`.

hope this helps!

Comment: This didn't work, but I tried `var second = parseInt($('#sidetextdyn').text());` . It seems to be taking the whole numbers up to the decimal and nothing after the decimal. How can it read the decimal as well?

Comment: Got it, used parsefloat!